Different traversals of a line graph with the same distance between adjacent nodes hit an endpoint at the same time
Suppose you have a path graph on $n$ nodes. Then take a permutation $s \in S_n$ and traverse the nodes in this order. Then this produces a sequence $a_1,...,a_{n-1}$ where $a_i = d(s(i),s(i+1)) = |s(i) - s(i+1)|$. So for example, with $n=6$ the identity permutation gives $11111$, or the permutation $421365$ gives $21231$.
Clearly more than one permutation (at least 2 by symmetry) can produce the same sequence $a_1,...,a_{n-1}$. My intuition however is that the first instance of hitting an endpoint is the same. That is, let $i$ be the first value such that $s(i)$ is an endpoint ($s(i) =1$ or $n$), then all permutations corresponding to $a_1,...,a_{n-1}$ have the same $i$. By symmetry, traversing in reverse, then the indices of both endpoint are fixed (up to reflection).
However, I'm having trouble trying to prove this (or even being sure if it is true). My intuition is that given a set of distances between nodes we can either spread these nodes out to have a big a span as possible, or minimize their span. So if one traversal hits an endpoint earlier than the other, it will be "ahead" of the other traversal and they can't give all the same remaining distance values. I was also trying to do some induction, but wasn't quite sure how.
I would greatly appreciate some insight, and also references on understanding these types of questions on line graphs if possible.

To clarify, by a line graph you mean a path graph, not the line graph of some arbitrary graph?

Yes sorry I mean a path graph on n nodes, I will fix that.

My first instinct with problems like these is to test them on small examples. In this instance, the Mathematica code
GatherBy[Permutations[Range[6]],Abs@*Differences] // Column

showed me all the permutations in $S_6$ partitioned by the sequence $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)$ that they form, and it's easy to spot a counterexample: $123645$ and $321465$ both result in the sequence of differences $(1,1,3,2,1)$, even though one of them begins at an endpoint, and the other only reaches an endpoint on its third step.
An even more interesting example is the pair $213645$ and $231465$, both with a sequence of differences of $(1,2,3,2,1)$, which accomplish this while neither starting nor ending at an endpoint!
An interesting sequence to look at is the number of possible difference sequences, depending on $n$. This sequence begins with the $10$ terms $$1, 1, 3, 9, 54, 267, 2166, 15788, 160222, 1528045, \dots$$ It does not appear to be in the OEIS.

I see thank you. I am interested in finding the indices of the endpoints of the graph given a hidden traversal, and only having the partition sequence. As you show, I see this is not possible. Do you have any ideas what other information might be sufficient?

Well, the signed differences would certainly do it, but that might be asking for too much. It depends on what other information is available to you.
